# How to restore fragment state after resume w/o savedInstanceState?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

in my app an `FragmentActivity` contains a simple `ListFragment` and I want to preserve the position to which the user has scrolled to. I did the following:

```
private int initialScrollPosition = 0;
private int initialScrollYOffset = 0;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(SCROLL_POSITION, this.getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition());
    View firstVisibleItemView = this.getListView().getChildAt(0);
    outState.putInt(SCROLL_Y_OFFSET, (firstVisibleItemView == null) ? 0 : firstVisibleItemView.getTop());
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    this.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}

private void restoreState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(SCROLL_POSITION)) {
        this.initialScrollPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(SCROLL_POSITION);
    }
    if(savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(SCROLL_Y_OFFSET)) {
        this.initialScrollYOffset = savedInstanceState.getInt(SCROLL_Y_OFFSET);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart () {
    super.onStart();
    // some other GUI stuff
    this.getListView().setSelectionFromTop(this.initialScrollPosition, this.initialScrollYOffset);
}
```

This solution works fine for things like display orientation changes or moving from one `Activity` of my app to the next.

But if I fire up the app, scroll a bit, go back to home, and restore the App from Recents, `onActivityCreated` (or any other callbacks with the `savedInstanceState` `Bundle`) is not called and therefore the state cannot be restored.

Therefore I have two questions:

1. What can I do to get the `savedInstanceState` after resuming without the `onXXXCreated` callbacks?
2. What exactly is the lifecycle doing there. I'd like to understand, why my approach fails.

Thank you very much for any insight!

**Solution:**

Thx to André! I changed my `onSaveInstanceState` to this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    this.initialScrollPosition = this.getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View firstVisibleItemView = this.getListView().getChildAt(0);
    this.initialScrollYOffset = (firstVisibleItemView == null) ? 0 : firstVisibleItemView.getTop();
    outState.putInt(SCROLL_POSITION, this.initialScrollPosition);
    outState.putInt(SCROLL_Y_OFFSET, this.initialScrollYOffset);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your app is brought to front using the recent apps button, it might be that it isn't recreated, because the system didn't finish it yet. In that case only `onResume()` and following callbacks are invoked.

Conclusion: try to restore your position in `onResume()`, store the positions in `onPause()` (for recent app switches where the activity isn't recreated), extract the positions from `savedInstanceState` bundle (for orientation change where the activity is recreated).